# How can i use Scrapy in conjunction with Mysql?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm trying to create a web crawler that, given some starting urls, extracts all  elements and follows them in order to extract the text inside  and .
I am running a Django application that, given a query string, returns all the items previously stored in a Mysql db.
The best option in my opinion would be to use Scrapy, give him some starting urls in which he'll find the others by simply extracting all the urls in the page and then, he'll follow them extracting the content of those pages.

1. Is it possible to insert the previously extracted data into a Mysql
   db (bacause i didn't find any information about this on scrapy.org)?
2. Is there a built in function to decide the "depth" of the scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just read all the scrapy docs, there might be a better way to do this but in the item pipeline i have just saved data there.  For each Item thaat is processed check if it already in your mysql and save it if its not! http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

For reading the "depth": Use the [DepthMiddleware](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=depth#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.depth). You can than read it from a request object like `request.meta['depth']`.

Comment: I added information on how to read the depth.